# Why is my regex failing to select the correct elements, when it works on the online regex tester

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, sed

I have a number of xml files, that has HTML embedded in a node . I need capture everything that is not the tags, add some non HTML tags (for moodle) around the text.

I'm processing the files from the command line, using a bash script.  I'm using xpath to get the content, piping through xargs to sneakily rip out newlines and then piping through sed.

Heres a sample of the  tag:

```
xpath -q -e '/activity/page/content' page.xml|xargs
<content>&lt;h3 style=float:right>&lt;img
src=@@PLUGINFILE@@/consumables.png> &lt;/h3> &lt;h3>TITLE&lt;/h3> 
&lt;p>In order to conduct an LE5 drug test you need a Druglizaer 
(batch controlled) foil pouch that contains two items:&lt;/p> 
&lt;p>&lt;/p> &lt;ol> &lt;li>&lt;span style=font- 
weight:900>Druglizer Cartridge&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;li>&lt;span 
style=font-weight:900>Druglizer Oral Fluid
Collector&lt;/span>&lt;/li> &lt;/ol> &lt;p>&lt;/p></content>
```

On https://regex101.com/ I used `\&gt;(.*?)\&lt;` which is grouping the text as expected. but when I run with sed it isn't doing any substitutions.

```sh
 #!/bin/bash
 # get new name string
 name=$(xpath -q -e '/activity/page/name' page.xml);
 en=$(echo $name|sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g');
 vi=$(echo $en|trans -brief -t vi);
 cn=$(echo $en|trans -brief -t zh-CN);
 mlang_name=$(echo "&#123;mlang en&#125;$en&#123;mlang&#125;&#123;mlang 
 vi&#125;$vi&#123;mlang&#125;&#123;mlang 
 zh_cn&#125;$cn&#123;mlang&#125;")
 # xmlstarlet to update node

 # get new content string
 content=$(xpath -q -e '/activity/page/content' page.xml);
 # \&gt;(.*?)\&lt;
 mlang_name=$(echo $content|sed -e 's/\&gt;(.*?)\&lt;/\&#123;mlang 
 en\&#125;$1\&#123;mlang\&#125;\&#123;mlang 
 vi\&#125;#VI#\&#123;mlang\&#125;\&#123;mlang 
 zh_cn\&#125;#CN#\&#123;mlang\&#125;/g')
 # xmlstarlet to update node
```

I need the replace to put {mlang en}TEXT{mlang} around the text.

Comment: Yes, I think you might be right. sed doesn't support the non-greedy .*?.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using perl as it supports the non-greedy format i was using.

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?>)(.*?)(&lt;.*?)/$1\{mlang en\}$2\{mlang\}$3/g'
```

With the above file, the full command I used was

```
content=$(xpath -q -e '/activity/page/content' page.xml);echo $content|xargs|sed -e 's/<|<content>//g'|sed -e 's|</content>||g'  |perl -pe 's/(.*?>)(.*?)(&lt;.*?)/$1\{mlang en\}$2\{mlang\}$3/g'|sed -e 's/{mlang en}[\ ]*{mlang}//g'|sed -e 's/<content>//g'
```

Which gave the following output

```
&lt;h3 style=float:right>&lt;img src=@@PLUGINFILE@@/consumables.png>&lt;/h3>&lt;h3>{mlang en}TITLE{mlang}&lt;/h3>&lt;p>{mlang en}In order to conduct an LE5 drug test you need a Druglizaer (batch controlled) foil pouch that contains two items:{mlang}&lt;/p>&lt;p>&lt;/p>&lt;ol>&lt;li>&lt;span style=font-weight:900>{mlang en}Druglizer LE5 Cartridge{mlang}&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;li>&lt;span style=font-weight:900>{mlang en}Druglizer Oral Fluid Collector{mlang}&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;/ol>&lt;p>&lt;/p>
```

If there's a more elegant way feel free to let me know.